# php function returning input

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am working on setting up a PHP function that will take inputs from a custom field (ACF-generated) on a page in the wordpress backend and generate HTML. Here's what i'm calling in my PHP/HTML files....

```
<?php connect_links('github', the_field( 'github_url', 94 ) ); ?>
```

and here is the code from my functions.php:

```
<?php
function connect_links($type, $url){
$email = '';
switch ($type) {
    case 'facebook':
        $fa_type = 'fa-facebook-official';
        break;
    case 'github':
        $fa_type = 'fa-github-square';
        break;
    case 'linkedin':
        $fa_type = 'fa-linkedin-square';
        break;
    case 'twitter':
        $fa_type = 'fa-twitter-square';
        break;
    case 'email':
        $fa_type = 'fa-envelope';
        $email = 'mailto:';
        break;
    default:
        $fa_type = 'no-fa-type';
        break;
}
?>
    <a href="<?php if($email) echo $email; echo $url; ?>">
        <i class="fa <?php echo $fa_type; ?> blue-and-white-icon"> </i>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

?>

Instead of getting the input from the wordpress backend and using it in the function, it runs as if it has no second input then takes the second input and prints it to the HTML in between elements.

My function works as expected when I call it with actual inputs like this:

```
connect_links('github', 'https://www.github.com/michaeljwiebe' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want get_field() which returns a value:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Unlike the_field() which prints a value.

Comment: thats very helpful. I had used get_field for variables but not so yet in functions. Thanks!

Comment: Well, function inputs are variable assignments.  The function assigns the input to $url